# " ... go to the gym almost every day" -- May I put "almost" before the verb?

Tags: word-usage, word-order

1. > I **almost** go to a local gym everyday.
2. > I go to a local gym **almost** everyday.

To me, sentence #2 is correct.  I just want to know if it is correct to put the word 'almost' before the verb 'go'.

Comment: Welcome to ELU!  You want to say *every day*, not *everyday*. *Everyday* is an adjective meaning *ordinary*, the sort of thing that happens *every day*.

Answer (score 4):

It is grammatical, but your two sentences mean two different things.

The first means you `almost got to the gym`, as if you got to the parking lot, and gave up and turned around, while the second means you go to the gym Monday-Friday, so not every day, but *almost* every day.

Comment: "Monday–Friday" is of course only an example; it could be any 5 (or 6) days of the week. But four out of seven probably wouldn't be considered "almost every day".  (btw I just now noticed that the ell in your user ID is not another tee)